# Send Cookie through WebBrowser in VB

Tags: vb.net

So I have sent close to two hours searching for an answer but nothing is working. I need to to send a few cookies through my webbrowser object but for some reason the cookies aren't being read by my PHP file:

```
<?php die('Your username is '.$_COOKIE['user']); ?>
```

And my VB code to send the cookies:

```
For i = 0 To 4
uploadBoxes(i).Navigate("about:blank")
uploadBoxes(i).Document.Cookie = "user=" & username.Text
uploadBoxes(i).Navigate("http://*****/uploader/app.php")
Next i
```

Again, any help would be appreciated and yes, I do need to send it over the webbrowser object. I also have browsed through MSDN database and even that has shed little light on this problem.

------------------------------------------ THE ANSWER -------------------------------------------------

So I took the InternetSetCookie method and came up with this code that worked on making the cookies:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

   ' No more data is available.
    Const ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259

    ' The data area passed to a system call is too small.
    Const ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122

    Private Declare Function InternetSetCookie Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "InternetSetCookieA" _
     (ByVal lpszUrlName As String, _
     ByVal lpszCookieName As String, _
     ByVal lpszCookieData As String) As Boolean

Private sub something()
              Dim bRet As Boolean
                bRet = InternetSetCookie("http://*****/uploader/app.php", _
                 "user", "admin")
                If bRet = False Then
                    MsgBox("Failed")
                End If
                uploadBoxes(i).Navigate("http:/*****/uploader/app.php")
End sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wininet.InternetSetCookie

```
  <DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
      Public Shared Function InternetSetCookie(lpszUrl As String, _
      lpszCookieName As String, lpszCookieData As String) As Boolean
     End Function

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Sub InternetSetCookiePseudoCode()
'`CookieCollection` was populated using HttpWebRequest/Response calls
Dim i As Integer = 0
InternetSetCookie("https://www.url.com/", Nothing, CookieCollection(i).ToString() & "; expires = Sun, 01-Jul-2014 00:00:00 GMT")
'repeat for however many cookies you've got

browser.Navigate("https://www.url.com/", True)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some old version i use to manually set cookies for the VB.Net Webbrowser Control:

```
    Private Declare Function InternetSetCookie Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetSetCookieA" (
        ByVal lpszUrlName As String,
        ByVal lpszCookieName As String,
        ByVal lpszCookieData As String) As Long
```

[...]

```
Dim CookieVal As String = "asdfghjkl12345"
Dim CookieNamestr As String = "sessionid"
Try
    Dim Result As Long = InternetSetCookie("https://www.url.com/", CookieNamestr, CookieVal )
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```